# Why is the MongoDB Java driver / Morphia prepending a property twice?

Tags: java, mongodb, syntax, morphia

Here are my (sample) objects.  I haven't put any other annotations besides what's required for Morphia:

```
package jungle;

@Entity
public class Monkey {
   String name;
   int bananas;
   @Embedded
   TreeHouse house;
}
```

And the `TreeHouse` object:

```
@Embedded
public class TreeHouse {
   String type;
   int distanceFromWater;
}
```

I'm trying to query on the `type` by using a regex.  Here's the MongoDB query that I'm using (and has been proven to work through the command line):

```
db.Monkey.find({ "house.type": { "$regex" : ".*coco.*", "$options": "i"}})
```

I'm able to generate this exact String in Java using the `filter` method from a `Query` object:

```
Query query = ...;
query = query.filter("house.type", 
              Pattern.compile(".*coco.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

However, when I try to run search in Java, I get a `ValidationException`:

```
com.google.code.morphia.query.ValidationException: The field 'house' could not be
  found in 'jungle.Monkey' while validating - house.house.type; if you wish to
  continue please disable validation.
```

*Note the doubling of `house.house.type`.*

I'm using version 0.99 of Morphia, and using version 2.5 of the MongoDB Java driver.  Am I not doing something correctly?  Or is this a problem that has been fixed in a newer version?

Answer (score 3):

Try this trick, it works for me:

```
query = query.disableValidation().filter("house.type", 
              Pattern.compile(".*coco.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```